# svn switch error - is not the same repository

Tags: svn

I have recently moved the SVN server and now i am tring to relocate the working copies from my computer to the new server. But i get the strangest error.
i do :

```
svn switch http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project/trunk/web
```

but i get

```
svn: 'http://99.99.99.old/svn/company/project/trunk/web'
is not the same repository as
'http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project'
```

the move was made with dump and import ... and the repo root is on http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project

Do you guys have any ideas of what might be wrong ? 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try using

```
svn switch --relocate http://99.99.99.old/svn/company/project/trunk/web http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project/trunk/web
```

As noted by Sporino in the comments, since Subversion 1.7, there's a seperate `relocate` command:

```
svn relocate http://99.99.99.old/svn/company/project/trunk/web http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project/trunk/web
```

Comment: @Steef so url should be identical to previous one exept, that it will be pointing to another location? So for example `svn switch --relocate .../project1/trunk/SomeDir .../project2/trunk` wount work, right? I need to have `svn switch --relocate .../project1/trunk/SomeDir .../project2/trunk/SomeDir`?

Comment: Since subversion 1.7 there is a new command called relocate to do the same.

Comment: @Eugene Relocate to the new "base location" with `svn switch --relocate http://old.location/svn/project/trunk http://new.location/svn/project/trunk`. This should not be an existing repository. Afterwards use the normal switch command to your repository `svn switch http://new.location/svn/projects/project/trunk`.

Answer (score 23):

Also, in TortoiseSVN there is "Relocate" option, which you should use in situations like these (instead of the "Switch" option).

Comment: agreed ... but i was on ubuntu so that options was not available :)

Answer (score 7):

My best way to do an SVN relocation is this:

```
svn switch --relocate $(svn info | grep ^URL | cut -f 2 --delim=' ') \
                      new_url_or_repository
```

In this way, using the right old url from the `svn info` command, you are sure to not enter a wrong one, which is one of the common erros.

If everything is correct, you will be prompted with the auth details for the new location, if they are different.

After issuing the command, be sure to double check that the change has been applied looking at the URL parameter, issuing

```
svn info
```

After relocating, update your working copy, to check that everything is ok:

```
svn update
```

My 2c ..

Answer (score 4):

Use the `relocate` command line parameter to the `switch` command.

[svn switch documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html)

> Sometimes an administrator might change the "base location" of your repository — in other words, the contents of the repository doesn't change, but the main URL used to reach the root of the repository does. For example, the hostname may change, or the URL schema, or perhaps just the path which leads to the repository. Rather than checkout a new working copy, you can have the svn switch command "rewrite" the the beginnings of all the URLs in your working copy. Use the --relocate command to do the substitution. No file contents are changed, nor is the repository contacted. It's similar to running a perl script over your working copy .svn/  directories which runs s/OldRoot/NewRoot/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the --relocate option :

```
svn switch --relocate http://99.99.99.new/svn/company/project/trunk/web
```

see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but as BastardSaint wrote you need to specify both from and to URLS

Comment: Just more of the poor UI design that irks me about subversion and SVK.  There may be exotic use-cases that require you to specify two URLs, but the tools should just take the damn default.  In SVK, for example, I shouldn't *NEED* to specify merge source and target, but I do.